# A very weird Laravel issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am getting this very weird issue in Laravel.

```
return $this->pending($input);
```

This method returns query result which is executed in it.
When I do this, I get the data that I need.

```
{
  "total": 51,
  "per_page": 5,
  "current_page": 1,
  "last_page": 11,
  "next_page_url": "link/to/api?page=2",
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "from": 1,
  "to": 5,
  "data": [
     //some data
   ]
}
```

However, when I tried doing this:

```
$response = array();
$response['pending'] = $this->pending($input);
```

I get a blank array.

```
{
  "pending": {}
}
```

Any idea why is this happening? I am sure the query is correct, because I am getting the expected result from the query.

Also, I tried doing this. And I am doing the same thing in function `pending`:

```
$data = User::paginate(5);
return $data;
```

This works.

But, this doesn't

```
$response = array();
$response['pending'] = User::paginate(5);
return $response;
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. What is the `pending` method do and what class is it a part of? What does the `$response` variable contain and where is it initialised? Please post all code that is relevant to the question and that is needed to provide a context for your problem.

Comment: $pending method has a query, which gives the result that I posted here. Apart from that I don't think any more information is required.

Comment: @phantomphoenix give us all the code include this pending function.. you have some error somewhere.. does $this->pending($input); return a collection?

Comment: @AmirBar: The pending function has a query. It is the result from that query that is returned. Query is working fine. No problem there.

Comment: what is the result of query? you have error do this test to see that you wrong:
$users = User::all(); var_dump($users); $response['pending'] = $users; var_dump ($response); $users ==  $response['pending']; you will get true; therefore you have some mistake somewhere just show us your code

Comment: @AmirBar: Updated the question. Can you see that?

Comment: return $response['pending'] is working?

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem

```
$response = array();
$response['pending'] = $this->pending($input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting empty because it is a collection, if you really want to use it

```
$data = Users::paginate(5);

return (array) $data;
```